# Send mass mail in Django -- Too many values to unpack

Tags: python, django

I'm experimenting with Django's mass_mail function.  The code below keeps raising a "Too Many Values to Unpack" error, and I can't figure out why.  I'm following the docs (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/email/#send-mass-mail) which seem pretty straightforward--what am I doing wrong?  If it matters, the send-email address is made up, but I can't see that mattering.

```
if matching_record.level == 1:
                users = self._get_users_to_be_notified(matching_record.category)
                email_recipients = [str(user.email) for user in users if user.email]
                message = 'Here is your requested notification that the service "%s" is having technical difficulties and has been set to "Critical".' %matching_record.name
                mail_tuple = ('Notification', 
                              message, 
                              'notifications@service.com', 
                              email_recipients)
                send_mass_mail(mail_tuple)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`send_mass_mail` method's first argument is a *tuple of message tuples*, but you are sending just a message tuple. Change the function calling like below and check if it works:

```
send_mass_mail((mail_tuple,))
```

Comment: Ugh, so simple!  Thank you!